# Windows authentication at remote stores

Tags: active-directory, monitoring, azure, remote-desktop

Our company has 15 stores each with high speed internet. At each store we have 2-3 Windows 10 PCs, with 3-4 employees per store (each employee does not work every day). All together we have about 40 PCs and 50 users. We would like all employees to sign in to their computer using a centralized authentication system. We don’t want to set up a VPN at each location back to our HQ’s Active Directory server.

Considering our HQ AD only has a few security policies and 10 computers attached, we could probably replace it with the Azure AD as well?

From what I have read, I believe Azure AD should be able to help us with this. Is this right? Or would we be better off using a true cloud AD product like JumpCloud?

If so, can we use multiple domain names (e.g. abc.com and xyz.com)?

Furthermore, we would like to be able to remotely monitor if the computer is running (thus, since this is done remotely it also has an internet connection),remotely perform windows updates, and also remotely share the screen for troubleshooting. I assume this is another question, but possible Microsoft has one product that can do this monitoring along with authentication?

Comment: This could be simple or complex. Do you want these to be cloud only users that authenticate to Azure AD? Do you want these user accounts in your on premises AD and have them synced to Azure AD? Do you want to register the computers in Azure AD or do you want to use Azure AD Join? Do you want to write these devices back to your on premises AD? Maybe provide more details on your use case for us.

Comment: Simple is better. The use case is explained above, no need to make it more complicated.

Answer (score 1):

> From what I have read, I believe Azure AD should be able to help us
>   with this. Is this right?

Yes, we can join your win 10 to Azure AD, and use Azure AD account to login this win 10.

About join Windows 10 to Azure AD, please refer to this [link](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/enterprisemobility/2016/02/17/azure-ad-domain-join-windows-10/).

> If so, can we use multiple domain names

As far as I know, this is not support.

> I assume this is another question, but possible Microsoft has one
>   product that can do this monitoring along with authentication?

To monitor those PCs, I think we can use Operations Management Suite(OMS), but OMS does not support remotely those PCs to do some troubleshooting.

More information about OMS, please refer to this [link](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/operations-management-suite/operations-management-suite-overview).